# reload sqlite every time access view

Tags: sqlite, uiview

I have one Tab Bat Controller and 2 UIView, in one view I insert or update the sqlite and the other view I read the sqlite data but when I access first time the view that read the sqlite the result is ok but when I insert or update the sqlite and then go to the other view the sqlite have the old results. I can see the new result only If I close the application and open again.

I want to know what I have to do to load the sqlite data every time that I access the results view.

For example: how I delete the sqlite memory to load again when I access the view with the new results from the database.

To get the results I do this:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)selectPossui{
    cromoList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[[self dataFilePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bd.sqlite"]];
    [database open];
    FMResultSet *result = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM cromo where possui = 1"];

    while ([result next]) {
        programmer = [[Coder alloc] init];
        programmer.codigo = [result stringForColumn:@"id"];
        programmer.possui = [result stringForColumn:@"possui"];
        programmer.repetida = [result stringForColumn:@"repetida"];
        [cromoList addObject:programmer];
        programmer=nil;
    }
    [database close];
    return cromoList;
}
```

Comment: Makes no sense.  SQLite returns what you ask for.  If you're getting an old result, you never asked for a new one.  I suspect you've conflated opening the DB and doing the query.

Comment: I updated my question...I don't know but I think that the sqlite is "in memory" If I close the application and open again I will see the new results.

Comment: You're not making sense.  The above sequence (assuming you didn't screw things up elsewhere) should produce the same sequence of values every time it's executed.

Comment: For example: I have one view with a button and every time that I click in this button I update the count in the sqlite...the other view show me the total of clicks...I put this code in my "viewDidLoad" and I think that I have to put in method to execute every time the view open

Comment: `viewDidLoad` doesn't execute every time the view is opened, only the first time.  Try `viewWillAppear`.